how to prevent Modal Bottom Sheet from getting close on swipe Down in compose
I am using Modal Bottom Sheet in my app. How can I prevent it from getting close on swipe down? I have a lazy column on the sheet. I want it only to get closed when I click on the close icon.
fun Preview(
    list: List<String>,
    onBottomSheetDismiss: (Boolean) -> Unit,
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val previewSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = false,
    )
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { onBottomSheetDismiss(false) },
        sheetState = previewSheetState,
        modifier = Modifier.height(700.dp),
        dragHandle = {
            Column {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(start = 15.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 5.dp, end = 10.dp),
                    Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {

               Text(text= "Preview")

                 CloseIcon(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            previewSheetState.hide()
                            onBottomSheetDismiss(false)
                        }
                    })
                }
                HorizontalDivider(thickness = 1.dp)
            }
        }
    ) {
       LazyColumn(){
           items(list){
            Text(text= "it")
           }
        }


Add a boolean variable isClosable to control when the bottom sheet can be closed. Then confirm state change to Hidden only when isClosable is true. Any state change resets isClosable to false.
var isClosable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val previewSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    skipPartiallyExpanded = false,
    confirmValueChange = { sheetValue ->
        if (sheetValue == SheetValue.Hidden && !isClosable) {
            false
        } else {
            isClosable = false
            true
        }
    }
)

Set isClosable to true before hiding the bottom sheet by the close icon:
CloseIcon(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        isClosable = true
        previewSheetState.hide()
        onBottomSheetDismiss(false)
    }
})

Edit:
An alternative way is to return false from confirmValueChange and hide the bottom sheet itself:
val previewSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    confirmValueChange = { false }
)
var showPreview by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Column {
    Button(onClick = { showPreview = true }) {
        Text("Show preview")
    }
}
if (showPreview) {
    //ModalBottomSheet
}

Close button:
CloseIcon(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        showPreview = false
        onBottomSheetDismiss(false)
    }
})


Thank you, It works. The sheet does not get close but it shrinks for a second while scrolling down. Can we stop it from shrinking, it should open up to a certain height and then stay there.

You can return false from confirmValueChange. But that would prevent it from expanding too. @PawandeepSingh

Check out my edit @PawandeepSingh

Hey Jan, Hope you are good. How can I prevent the modal sheet from being dragged down when I scroll the lazy list? Once it is open it should not move until the close button is clicked.

Hello @PawandeepSingh. There is a way to disable nested scroll, but it's inconsistent and modal bottom sheet will still move sometimes. I don't think there is a reliable way to make it work like you need except using the material version. Or what about not using bottom sheet at all if you don't need it's functionality? Perhaps a dialog would fit better?

okay, yeah dialog will work, thanks for replying
